# What method of finding the square root they use in this screenshot?

Tags: numerical-methods, arithmetic, radicals

I saw somewhere a screenshot from a old(?) Russian cartoon with the following math inside. On a screenshot one can see that a student successfully solves 2 exercises on finding square root and receives an excellent mark.

[image]

Here are the important bits:

**Left exercise** Compute $\sqrt{9 511 936}$ with $0.01$ precision
\begin{align}
\newcommand\ph[1]{\color{white}{#1}}
&\ph{60}\hspace{-1em}\sqrt{9'51'19'56'} = 3084.14\\
&\ph{60}9\\
&\overline{608|511'9}\\
&\ph{60}8|1364\\
&\overline{6164|2555'6}\\
&\ph{608}4|24656\\
&\overline{61631|\ph{0}9000'0}\\
&\ph{6080}1|\ph{0}61681\\
&\overline{616834|283190'0}\\
&\ph{60803}4|2467296\\
&\overline{\ph{616834|2}364604}\\
\end{align}
Answer $3084.14$

**Right exercise** Find $\sqrt{123904}$
\begin{align}
\newcommand\ph[1]{\color{white}{#1}}
&\hspace{-1em}\sqrt{12'39'04} = 352\\
&\ph{1}9\\
&\overline{65|33'9}\\
&\ph{6}5|325\\
&\overline{702|140'4}\\
&\ph{60}2|1404\\
&\overline{\ph{702|2}0}\\
\end{align}

Answer is $352$

**My thoughts.** I understand the part of splitting the number by two digits. I understand the first step of guessing the first digit, but then I have no idea what is going on. Who they get $65$ in the second example? Could one guess the whole procedure or give a link explaining it? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm

Comment: The one they have shown in the comic is outlined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation

Shifting nth root algorithm is a generalization of this method.

Comment: Known as the "Long Division Method for Finding Square Roots". You can Google it

Comment: Thanks, I guess the numbers on the right are just $20p+x$ from the Wikipedia link. So $65 = 20\times3 + 5$